# Sending data to an li in jquery that already has data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a problem here. I need to send data to a `li` in my `ul` that is already there with bunch of other `li`'s.

Here is where i make the list:

```javascript
lijst = $("<li/>") 
  .appendTo("#deals")
  .data('stadnaam', oPlaats.Stad)
  .click(function() {
    showWeather($(this).data('stadnaam'));
  });

$("<span/>")
  .text(oPlaats.Prijs)
  .addClass("price")
  .appendTo(lijst);

$("<strong/>")
  .text(oPlaats.Stad)
  .appendTo(lijst);

$("<span/>")
.text(oPlaats.Land)
.appendTo(lijst);
```

If you click on it then there should be 2 more divs in that ul. How can I do that? I now do it like this but it places the date in the last li:

```javascript
$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst);

$("<div/>")
  .text(celsius)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst);

$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst);

$("<div/>")
  .text(oWeather[j].main)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst);
```

Comment: @epascarello `bool(true)` :) just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the new elements to the UL, and not the LI, you should append it to the parent of your element:

```
$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst.parent());

$("<div/>")
  .text(celsius)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst.parent());

$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst.parent());

$("<div/>")
  .text(oWeather[j].main)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst.parent());
```

Another way is to do as follows:

```
$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst.closest('ul'));

$("<div/>")
  .text(celsius)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst.closest('ul'));

$("<br/>")
  .appendTo(lijst.closest('ul'));

$("<div/>")
  .text(oWeather[j].main)
  .addClass("weather")
  .appendTo(lijst.closest('ul'));
```

But I recomend using the parent() function. Let me know if this solves your problem.

## EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:

You should add a click event to the lijst var:

```
lijst.click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var div = $('<div />');

    self.append(div);
});
```

Comment: No it doesnt now it get placed after the ul

Comment: I dont get it, you want to add the elements to the UL? if you want it in the beggining of the UL you can replace appendTo for prependTo

Comment: No ul is my list. It's called #deals. Lijst is every seperate li in that ul. Every li has a .data(stadnaam, ...) Now AFter someone clicks on it I need to add some more data into that li how can i find and edit that li.